# Conditionally toggling CSS on $(window).resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run the following script and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm very much a noob and this is literally me testing and trying to figure out how things work. There's probably better ways to do what I'm doing here or maybe I'm just misunderstanding the functions.

Basically, I made a link, gave it the class of `.home` and am toggling `visibility`. The first snippet of code to do so works just fine.

I then decided to mess around with the `$(window).resize();` function to do another toggle when a resize is detected. This part isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Click Toggle
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        if ($('.home').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('.home').css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $('.home').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });

    //showHome
    var showHome = function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 799) {
            $('.home').css('visibility', 'visible');
        };
    };

    $(window).resize(showHome);
    showHome();

});
```

Comment: Could you make this into a fiddle/snippet example?

Comment: I don't think there's a need for that here @SpencerWieczorek - it's relatively straight-forward code.

Comment: OP - there are no errors in this code, assuming `.home` exists. I could give you some advice regarding alternative approaches - but as it stands your code is error-free. I suspect it's just not behaving as you'd expect. In which case you'll have to be as specific as possible.

Comment: `This part isn't working.` isn't working isn't much of a problem description. What isn't working? Does it do nothing at all? Does it give you errors in your console? Does it execute the handler but not do what you expected?

Comment: What is not working? Does it go into the if. Debug it. `console.log()` is your friend.

Comment: One thing I see that may have something to do with it is your call to the showHome function inside of "$(window).resize(showHome);" is missing the parentheses, ie. should be "showHome()".

Comment: @JonathanBowman thats because its a reference to the function. otherwise the function would be called as soon as the parser gets to that line, which is not intended.

Comment: @JonathanBowman - that's wrong, mate. It shouldn't. You're getting confused with passing an anonymous function I suspect.

Comment: @JonathanBowman That is wrong

Comment: @JonathanBowman: No it isn't. The OP is passing the function, not executing the function.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Then this question is off-topic, there are no errors with the code you provided. You also need to state what the problem is.

Comment: Ah, yup you're absolutely right - my mistake!

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - why is it off-topic? Because it's straight-forward? Nothing wrong with a concise, self-contained question.

Comment: Because the OP isn't stating the problem, it's unclear what the problem is - *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."*

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - what's that got to do with creating a jsfiddle? You've missed the point. You said `Then this question is off-topic` in response to `it's relatively straight-forward`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Uh, not sure if there's some confusion, but JᴀʏMᴇᴇ isn't the OP (though you seem to be addressing him as such). On the topic of the question though, I do agree that the OP is really lacking a clear problem statement - making it hard to discern what's actually wrong.

Comment: @JayMee: "This part isn't working." isn't a problem description. I believe that is what Spencer is picking up on (as I did also). I'm not sure why he is address these comments to you however since you are not the OP.

Comment: @Serlite Oh, sorry I didn't notice. (Edited my last comment)

Comment: I've lost track a little bit here. All I was trying to say was that ambiguity in a question can't (and shouldn't) be tackled with a jsfiddle. Especially since it makes the question 'less self-contained'. Granted, the question needs some clarity (which is why I can't answer it yet).

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ They can also use a stack snippet, I was merely asking to verify that `resize` is being called and is working ( and remove the possibly of errors elsewhere ), then and ask for clarification on what the problem is in that example.

Comment: First off, thank you guys for all the responses.

Comment: I did notice something while making this fiddle, I was able to get it to work but not as expected. My actual window was quite large (on a 1920 x1080 monitor). Even running Chrome in fullscreen the JS didn't work until I changed that 799 to 500. So it appears that maybe I'm misunderstanding what the window.width actually is. Granted, this could be because of how JSFiddle divides up it's code and active windows but still, this might be me misunderstanding the width: https://jsfiddle.net/8sspeh86/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `else` -- what to do when the screen is narrower than `799px`?

```js
//Click Toggle
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.home').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
    $('.home').css('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
    $('.home').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
});

//showHome
var showHome = function() {

  if ($(window).width() > 799) {
    $('.home').css('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
    $('.home').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
};

$(window).resize(showHome);
showHome();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>other stuff</p>

<p class="home">HOME</p>

<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Not sure why somebody would downvote this. It isn't entirely clear what the OP thinks the problem is (since they didn't really define "not working"), but if their aim was to toggle (which they said it was), then the problem is, indeed, that they don't actually toggle. This answer does.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what I was doing wrong. Looks like the code was fine. What I was doing wrong was so stupid I won't even say what it was. Suffice to say, trying to practice writing code while also working a busy job that requires 3 monitors isn't always a good idea.

Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: For the sake of future noobs, Please post the answer. In fact, you put this in an answer. If it is just a comment, then put it as a comment. Rather than that, post the actual answer and accept it. Oh, and a fiddle could be useful so future noobs can play around with it. If you don't know what jsfiddle is, here you go...http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/r907kfor/

Comment: For that matter, since Paul Roub's answer below works, you might consider accepting his answer.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted that answer and I actually did post a fiddle in response to the OP.

Comment: Nice job. BTW, you are the OP -- "**O**riginal **P**oster" ;) And take a look at my fiddle because it reports the windows size, so you can watch it change.